# Java process, swap (/proc Solaris10) memory highly utilized

Tags: solaris, java, swap, dtrace

How can I analyze high swap memory utilization of Solaris 10 for Java processes?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to start is start looking at Using DTrace for Solaris 10

- http://dsc.sun.com/solaris/articles/java_on_solaris.html
- http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/DTrace_Topics_Java
- http://blogs.oracle.com/jimlaurent/entry/solaris_faq_myths_and_facts
- http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/chrismay/entry/solaris_10_memory/
- http://www.solarisinternals.com/si/tools/memtool/vmsizing.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You will propably have to look at what the garbage collector is doing.
[SDN](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/GCPortal/) has a nice technical article about it (and how to enable debug for gc).

A nice practical approach is described [here](http://www.testing-software.org/tools/gcview.html). We normally use the mentioned gcview for this task (on Linux, but OS should not matter in this case).